# Regular expression to accept negative number

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression below:

```
^([0-9]+,)*[0-9]+$
```

This will validate the input from a user to accept positive or negative numbers only that is comma separated or dash.

```
123,123,10
10,10
25
-25,10
```

My regular expression above is only working for positive numbers and comma separator. How can I modify this to work with dash (10-25-30) and negative numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by positive number?

Comment: A satisfactory answer will insist on (i) no commas at all or (ii) commas placed after every 3 digits. And even this assumes US and UK-style numbers. Better IMO to validate a number string by trying to parse it to a number.

Comment: Your expression also accepts `00000000,0,0000,0,0` - is that fine?

Comment: @georg - it should not accept `00.....`, only `0`. thanks for figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^([-+]?[0-9]+[-,])*[+-]?[0-9]+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sI7xH7/2)

Comment: This is good however if the last number is negative, it won't work

Comment: Ah that's right, I updated the regex and demo link now.

Answer (score 5):

Just add a minus sign before and make it optional:

```
^-?([0-9]+[-,])*[0-9]+$
```

Comment: Slightly compact to use \d+ instead of [0-9]+

Comment: But \d+ does emit Arabic numerals which the OP just might not want.

Comment: @Yetti99: \d is same as \p{Digit}, it matches more than [0-9], it includes unicode digits and depends on locale. See: perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html